# "Scalar found where operator expected" in Perl substitution

Tags: regex, perl, backreference

I'm trying to increment a version number in a file using Perl. I want to change this line:

```
Bundle-Version: 1.0.2
```

to

```
Bundle-Version: 1.0.3
```

I thought I could do this using the following regex substitution:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(Bundle-Version: \d+.\d+.)(\d+)/$1$2+1/e;' MANIFEST.MF
```

But I get the following error:

```
Scalar found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "$1$2"
(Missing operator before $2?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "$1$2"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Could somebody please advise what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The `/e` flag makes Perl treat the RHS as an expression, so you might fix your current code using `'s/(Bundle-Version: \d+.\d+.)(\d+)/$1 . ($2+1)/e;'`, but you can simplify it a bit and use

```bash
perl -i -pe 's/Bundle-Version:\s*\d+\.\d+\.\K(\d+)/$1+1/e;' MANIFEST.MF
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/3CUnYX).

*Details*:

- `Bundle-Version:` - a fixed string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\d+\.\d+\.` - two sequences of one or more digits and a dot
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (`$1`): one or more digits

Comment: `s/Bundle-Version:\s*\d+\.\d+\.\K\d+/$&+1/e` (3 fewer chars)